# Problemas de Redirecionamento com .HTACCESS

Tags: html, htaccess

Eu estou desenvolvendo meu site e ele está em ótimas condições, no entanto estou com um pequeno problema na questão de redirecionamentos do site.
O link do meu site é esse: [Site - Lougans](https://lougans.com.br)

Eu criei no meu **.htaccess** algumas regras e condições que fazem o seguinte:

1. Remove a **barra (/)** final após o **.br** caso exista e redireciona;
2. Remove o **www** caso exista e redireciona;
3. Remove o **/index.php** após o **.br** caso exista e redireciona;
4. Redireciona para **HTTPS** se for solicitado o **HTTP**;

Tudo isso eu fiz para evitar **URL Canônica** e otimizar meu **SEO**. Bom, quando eu fiz essas regras, eu testei e elas funcionaram perfeitamente. 
Mas eu passei por um problema porque meu site estava esperando a ativação do SSL pela Hosgator e ainda não esta indo para **HTTPS**, mas quando ele começou a ser solicitado, ficou normal. 
Depois disso comecei a perceber o problema (a raiz da pergunta aqui):

Quando eu digitava com **barra (/)** ou **www** ou **/index.php** ou com **HTTP** ele redirecionava para isso:

`https://lougans.com.br/https://lougans.com.br/`

E agora está assim. Todos os links públicos na internet estão redirecionando para o link correto e o site está abrindo, mas saber que por trás disso tem esse erro e ainda não consegui resolver, está me deixando aflito.

**NOTA: Quando eu audito o site pelo Plugin Lighthouse, ao invés dele retornar para o site normal, ele vai para essa URL duplicada;**

Abaixo eu vou colocar todo o meu código **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Redireciona caso o URL informado vier com HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www.)?lougans.com.br/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|png|webp|js|css)$ - [F]

# Redireciona caso haja WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redireciona caso haja index.php
RewriteCond    %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

# Redireciona caso haja / no final
RewriteCond    %{HTTP_HOST} !^\. [NC]
RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Cache Headers
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
  # Cache specified files for 31 days
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|webp|gif|js|css|xml|gz|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache HTML files for a couple hours
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache PDFs for a day
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache Javascripts for 31 days
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

# Use the GZIP Apache module
<ifModule mod_gzip.c> 
    mod_gzip_on Yes 
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes 
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$ 
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$ mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.* 
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.* 
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.* 
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.* 
</ifModule> 

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType application/javascript .js2
    AddType text/javascript .js3
    AddType text/x-js .js4
    AddType text/html .html .htm
    AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
    AddType text/plain .txt
    AddType text/xsd .xsd
    AddType text/xsl .xsl
    AddType text/xml .xml
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType image/bmp .bmp
    AddType application/java .class
    AddType video/divx .divx
    AddType application/msword .doc .docx
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType application/json .json
    AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
    AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
    AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
    AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
    AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype .otf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType application/pdf .pdf
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType image/webp .webp
    AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
    AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
    AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype .ttf .ttc
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma
    AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
    AddType application/font-woff .woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
    AddType application/zip .zip
    AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/webp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|LESS|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|webp|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Essa é minha dúvida e peço que me ajudem. Outra coisa muito importante: Eu me dediquei mesmo elaborando essa pergunta e apresentando todos os dados relevantes para passar pra vocês, então antes de ficar saindo dando "NEGATIVE" nas perguntas, manda uma mensagem pedindo para eu melhorar a questão, ok? Me passe umas dicas e quem sabe eu não melhore, certo?
*(P.S: Este é só um comentário. Atenha-se a pergunta principal)*

Edições são sempre bem vindas!! Muito obrigado a todos que partilharem sua ajuda e experiência sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema comentando o `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` completamente e com isso o meu site voltou a ser acessado com:

1. **/index.php**;
2. **www**;
3. ter **barra (/)**;
4. **HTTP** sem redirecionar;

Comecei então a escrever regra por regra de uma forma um pouco diferente, porque o que me consta foi que uma ou mais instruções estavam conflitando com as demais regras. As regras finais ficaram assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# Redireciona caso o URL informado vier com HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www.)?lougans.com.br/.*$ [NC]
# RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|png|webp|js|css)$ - [F]

# Redireciona caso haja WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# Redireciona caso haja index.php
RewriteCond    %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

# Redireciona caso haja / no final
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Legal né?
Alem do mais, fica a dica para inserir isso em seus arquivos para evitar **URL Canônica duplicada** e prejudicar no **SEO** da página.

**NOTA IMPORTANTE:** Caso você encontre essa pergunta para resolver um problema seu semelhante, compare o **.htaccess** da pergunta com o **.htaccess** dessa resposta para ver o que foi modificado. Elas estão diferentes. :)

Valeu a todos e até a proxima!!!